# how to write data in to pdf using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

using `Pdfsharp`

```
 PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
 document.Info.Title = "Title";

 // Create an empty page
 PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

 // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
 XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

 // Create a font
 XFont font = new XFont("mationHC39M", 6);
```

here its taking font from cilent system..i want add the font from server..
this would be `Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + "\\Content\\mationHC39M.ttf`
how to put this path in the above code...

or how to add font from this path....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with Pdfsharp, but if you are willing to pay for a license key, I've used Winnovative HTML to PDF many times in the past with great ease:

http://www.winnovative-software.com/html-To-Pdf-Converter.aspx

You would simply create the PDF document in an ASP.NET page, then pass the URL, and it will stream a PDF document. Theres some sample code available.

Comment: sorry paying its not possible